# Xamarin Forms (Core/Portable) creates more Android permissions

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a rather complicated application and just now notice the fact that my app asks for a lot more permissions then I put in the AndroidManifest.xml. In my App.Droid Debug obj map there is a version of the AndroidManifest.xml (this is also the file in the Releases build) which has about 10-15 more permissions then I setup. 
For example the Accounts permission shows up, but I am not using that function.

Can anyone explain where these come from and how they can be reduced?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would need to look at the Nugets/3rd-party libraries that you are using and what they require. The case of `Accounts` permission might be coming from a library that stores user id/password, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Two things I know that can do that would be assembly annotation that you added in code and libraries that you installed requesting those permissions.

For the former, search your solution for `assembly: Permission` and `assembly: UsesPermission`. That should show you any you added in your code.

As far as finding out what your libraries are doing, I do not know a good way of finding that out other than manually looking at their documentation. For example the GCM plugin automatically adds the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permissions.

According to Android documentation you can remove that permission request by adding the following to your AndroidManifest.xml file, but it would never work for me for some reason (note the `tools:node="remove"`), not sure if the below does not apply to plugins or what the issue was:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" tools:node="remove" />
```

If you try the `tools:node` method, make sure to add the following to the `manifest` tag:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          ...>
```

If it works for you, let me know!

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. Only work on it on fridays. The tools:node seems to make it into the "final" manifest, but the permissions are still visible in the appmanager > permissions > more permissions. So it does not get removed... Im now removing packages, looking if it will build without errors. If you have another idea, please let me know.

Comment: Android manifest merge tools aren't available for use on the Xamarin Platform, unfortunately. https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=48153

Comment: @KenSykora Thanks so much for the info!! Thought I was just doing something wrong. Will try to update this post if they ever fix the bug/add the feature.

Comment: Feature request here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52857